# cannot understand why function keep getting called on d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

While studying code from below example, I think I almost got everything

http://jsfiddle.net/peDzT/

except I cannot for the life of me see how tick() continues to get called.(meaning, while that function continues to run and therefore continues to update the graph.

tick does not get called and there is no setinterval or anything like that. I also don't understand what .each("end", tick) does. Can someone please advise? This is using d3.js

```
tick();
function tick() {
  // push a new data point onto the back
  data.push(random());
  // redraw the line, and slide it to the left
  path
      .attr("d", line)
      .attr("transform", null)
    .transition()
      .duration(500)
      .ease("linear")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + x(-1) + ",0)")
      .each("end", tick);
  // pop the old data point off the front
  data.shift();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two things you are confused about are connected. [#each](https://github.com/d3/d3/wiki/Transitions#control) is used to handle transition events. An example of this is the `end` event, triggered after the transition finishes. This code is saying "after the transition finishes (i.e. when the `end` event is triggered), call `tick`. This will start a new transition and the same thing will repeat, calling `tick` again.

Comment: I could not find any doc on this. Do you have that information as well?

Comment: Take a look at the #each link. Sorry if that wasn't clear.

Comment: Excellent! thank you and answer accepted "If type is not specified, behaves similarly to selection.each: immediately invokes the specified function for each element in the current transition, passing in the current datum d and index i, with the this context of the current DOM element."

Comment: That line makes it clear that tick is the function and is invoked, but note that type *is* specified here and the 'The end event is invoked during ...' paragraph may be worth reading.

Comment: Thank you and I see what you mean. So, I guess it means in my code example, tick function will run after doing duration/ease/transform.. unless it's interrupted and in that case, tick might not run. This is so complicated but exciting. I must check out transition.transition. thank you so much!